# Image from DB won't display in JSP: No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, dispatcher

I got this in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView details(@Valid @ModelAttribute("MessageForm") final MessageForm form, @RequestParam("publicationid") String publicationid) {
    final Publication pub = ps.findById(Integer.valueOf(publicationid));
    final User user = us.findById(pub.getUserid());
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("details");
    long myid = pub.getPublicationid();

    UploadFile ufa = imageServiceImp.findFirstById(Long.parseLong(publicationid));
    System.out.println("mi publication id es " +ufa.getPublicationId());
    System.out.println("mi id de upload es " + ufa.getId());
    System.out.println("mis bytes son " + ufa.getData().toString());
   // these prints work fine

    try {
        Image img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(ufa.getData()));
        mav.addObject("image1", img);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //other stuff
    return mav;
}
```

So I made the following in my JSP to display the image:

```
  <img class="mySlides" src="<c:out value="${image1}" />" >
```

Turns out I get the following message when I get into this page trying my program (the image of course doesn't display):

```
 Sep 26, 2018 11:27:23 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
 WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/null/meinHaus/BufferedImage@4c8d98b4:%20type%20=%205%20ColorModel:%20] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

What could be happening?

I'm using spring-mvc.

Also getData() returns an array of type byte[].

Comment: The `img src` paramater is supposed to point to an URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way you should load images.

Write a method in controller class like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/getProfilePic/{uniqueId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getProfilePic(@PathVariable long uniqueId) {

        try{ 
            //reading image from tomcat folder you can read from the place where you stored the images
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            String profilePicDirectory = rootPath + File.separator + "profilePictures" + File.separator  + uniqueId;
            String profilePicFile = profilePicDirectory +  File.separator + uniqueId +".jpg";

            RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(profilePicFile, "r");
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            f.readFully(b);
            f.close();
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(b, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            //ex.printStackTrace();
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(null, headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            //return null;
        }
    }
```

then in jsp page call this url to load the image.

```
<img class="mySlides" src="/users/getProfilePic/${imageUniqueIdURL}" />
```

Comment: THank you, I adapted the code a little (removed the use of RandomAccesFile and used the bytes provided by my method).